Clonei uns arquivos de um repositorio e agora quero enviar para outro repositorio, como faco para mudar?
Clonei um arquivo no git para o meu computador e agora que editei quero enviar para um novo repositorio que criei no meu git. Como envio para outro repositorio se os arquivos estao conectados ao repositorio que clonei?
Abaixo foi o que aconteceu quando eu tentei... ai me dei conta que estava conectado ao repositorio clonado (espero ter conseguido explicar, sou iniciante nessa area).
User@DESKTOP-0UHRIRT MINGW64 /c/xampp/htdocs/alldoctors (raissateste)
$ git init
Reinitialized existing Git repository in C:/xampp/htdocs/alldoctors/.git/
User@DESKTOP-0UHRIRT MINGW64 /c/xampp/htdocs/alldoctors (raissateste)
$ git add README.md
User@DESKTOP-0UHRIRT MINGW64 /c/xampp/htdocs/alldoctors (raissateste)
$ git commit -m ""
On branch raissateste
Your branch is up to date with 'origin/raissateste'.
Changes not staged for commit:
(use "git add ..." to update what will be committed)
(use "git restore ..." to discard changes in working directory)
modified:   application/Model/Paciente.php
modified:   application/config/config.php
modified:   vendor/autoload.php
modified:   vendor/composer/ClassLoader.php
modified:   vendor/composer/InstalledVersions.php
modified:   vendor/composer/LICENSE
modified:   vendor/composer/autoload_classmap.php
modified:   vendor/composer/autoload_namespaces.php
modified:   vendor/composer/autoload_psr4.php
modified:   vendor/composer/autoload_real.php
modified:   vendor/composer/autoload_static.php
modified:   vendor/composer/installed.json
modified:   vendor/composer/installed.php
modified:   vendor/composer/platform_check.php
Untracked files:
(use "git add ..." to include in what will be committed)
application/Controller/PacienteTesteController.php
application/Model/PacienteTeste.php
application/view/paciente_teste/
no changes added to commit (use "git add" and/or "git commit -a")
User@DESKTOP-0UHRIRT MINGW64 /c/xampp/htdocs/alldoctors (raissateste)
$

Basta apenas habilitar para conseguir ver pastas ocultas no seu sistema operacional e excluir a pasta ".git", então é so iniciar um novo repositório no seu projeto no terminal.
Se estiver usando VsCode é ainda mais fácil, basta ir em source control nos 3 pontinhos opção remote, la tem como você remover o repositório remoto atual e adicionar o seu através da url que o git te fornece.
